# Not able to close IE 11 browser using "X" icon after pressing "stay on this page" by using Ctrl + w

Tags: javascript, html

Please find the sample below to test the issue, and the detailed step is as follows,

1. Create a html page by copy&paste the below content.
2. Open the html page using IE 11 browser
3. Use CTRL+W
4. Popup will be thrown asking two options,

   1. Leave this Page
   2. Stay on this page
5. Click on Stay on this page
6. Now press close "X" icon at the right corner of the browser.
   7 .Nothing happens-not able to close the browser

Is there any solution for this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Title>Test</Title>
<body>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = check;
function check()
{   
    return "Any unsaved changes will be lost";
}
</script>
<h3><p>Testing CTRL+W</p></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should write to MS support with this, not Stack Overflow...

Comment: Also, this is _not_ the right way to do this. Use an event listener in the first place, and then use a anonymous function with a confirm dialog! Like this: `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){ return confirm('Any unsaved changes will be lost!'); })` That should fix any issues - as here you are _always_ returning something other than false, preventing any unload from happening.

Comment: @somethinghere The [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) is designed to have a string returned from it's handler function and browsers implement this with a popup that displays the text returned.  (Unless it's Firefox, in which case it pops up a dialog without the text "for security reasons")

Comment: Also note the behaviour is different for documents served over file:// in that the dialog is not displayed when clicking X on another tab.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I was convinced it worked differently, but I was proven wrong :) I still think an event listener is better, as replacing `window.[event]` is never advisable. But otherwise, yes.

Comment: @somethinghere Yes - attaching to the event is still better unless you've got good reason not to

Answer (score 2):

If I click the X icon to close the browser, it will just return me the same alert of `CTRL+W` , and if I choose Exit the browser just close. So wehre is the problem of your question?

Comment: More appropriate as a comment, but okay.

Comment: I couldn't comment direclty your post cause I don't have 50 reputation... that's why....

Comment: I know, that's why I did upvote you. If you want to turn this into a real answer, maybe try to improve his code at least a little bit (you can use my suggestion from the comments if you want). His code isn't very proper right now.